# Loading a HTML file to an output stream

Tags: java, html, proxy, server

I'm currently attempting to make a proxy server.
The part I'm working on at the moment is to blocked certain URLs.

I created a basic HTML page that should show up whenever a blocked URL is entered but it's not currently working.

Here is the code for that section of my server.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("filePath") );
String htmlString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
scanner.close();
byte htmlBytes[] = htmlString.getBytes("UTF-8");
toClient.write(htmlBytes);
```

toClient is the output stream of my browser i.e

```
client = mySocket.accept();
OutputStream toClient = client.getOutputStream();
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is in the file `filepath`?  You'll need to send all the HTTP headers to the client first for the browser to understand it.

Comment: @SteveSmith filepath is a basic HTML file I created which simply says the URL is blocked.

Comment: You need to send the correct HTTP response headers first.

Answer (score 1):

The response must contain the header information as below.

```
OutputStream clientOutput = client.getOutputStream();

clientOutput.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
clientOutput.write(("ContentType: text/html\r\n").getBytes());
clientOutput.write("\r\n".getBytes());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("server.html"));
String htmlString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
scanner.close();
clientOutput.write(htmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

clientOutput.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
clientOutput.flush();
```